# "systemd-tmpfiles --clean" problem

Tags: debian, ubuntu, systemd

I want to cleanup a directory with systemd-tmpfiles.
On my ubuntu 22 server ***man tmpfiles.d*** shows the following example:

```
# Files created and modified, and directories accessed more than
# an hour ago in "/tmp/foo/bar", are subject to time-based cleanup.
d /tmp/foo/bar - - - - bmA:1h -
```

I have used this as a template and created the following cleanup specification:

```
d /var/mytmp 1777 root root - bmA:1h -
```

Running the command below gave an error, though

```
systemd-tmpfiles --clean /etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf 
/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:6: d lines don't take argument fields, ignoring.
```

I assumed that the man page has a typo, so I did change the specification to

```
d /var/mytmp 1777 root root bmA:1h
```

and that seems to work.
Then I tried the same line on my banana-pi which runs debian 11.5 (bullseye) but there I get:

```
/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:11: Invalid age 'bmA:30d'
```

The man page for tmpfiles.d looks slightly different on debian and it seems the age specification cannot be restricted to certain aspects as with ubuntu 22.

How can I specify the age to achieve my goal?